# Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'ActionsAll' （union Type of all actions） when React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, dispatch

I think 'ActionsAll' has contained the payload. feel confused about this. Is someone can help me. Thanks.

`actions.tsx` and `reducer.tsx` are as followings.

```
// action.tsx
import * as types from './constants';

export interface FetchValueBegin {
  type: string;
}

export interface FetchValueSuccess {
  type: string;
  payload: {
    valueType: string;
    value: number;
  }
}

export interface FetchValueError {
  type: string;
}

export type ActionsAll = FetchValueBegin
| FetchValueSuccess
| FetchValueError;

export const fetchValueBegin = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_VALUE_BEGIN,
});

export const fetchValueSuccess = (valueType: string, value: number) => ({
  type: types.FETCH_VALUE_SUCCESS,
  payload: { valueType, value },
});

export const fetchValueError = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_VALUE_ERROR,
});
```

```
// reducer.tsx
import { StoreState } from '../types';
import { ActionsAll } from './actions';
import { FETCH_VALUE_BEGIN, FETCH_VALUE_SUCCESS, FETCH_VALUE_ERROR } from './actions/constants';

const initState: StoreState = {
  languageName: 'TypeScript',
  enthusiasmLevel: 1,
  isError: null,
  errorToShow: '',
};

export function reducer(state = initState, action: ActionsAll): StoreState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_VALUE_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isError: null,
        errorToShow: '',
      };
    case FETCH_VALUE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        enthusiasmLevel: action.payload.valueType === 'add'
          ? state.enthusiasmLevel + action.payload.value
          : state.enthusiasmLevel - action.payload.value,
      };
    case FETCH_VALUE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isError: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

The first answer here is that **[you *should* be using Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-redux-toolkit-for-writing-redux-logic)**.  We specifically recommend *against* trying to write reducers and actions by hand today.  We do have a ["Redux Fundamentals" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview) in our docs that shows how to hand-write Redux code, but *only* so that you understand the basic mechanics.  For any actual app, you *should* be using RTK.

The second observation is that [you *should not* be writing TS action type unions](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#avoid-action-type-unions) - they don't provide any real benefit, and don't actually represent how the code runs.

Please follow the approach shown in [our Redux TS Quick Start docs page](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start) instead.